# If/else amp script logic for a custom landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

we are currently in the process of developing a custom preference centre via cloud pages. In one of the tabs we ask users for region/travel preferences. We have 6 checkboxes corresponding to 6 regions.

We will restrict the submissions to 3 options via the UX. We are saving these values both in Marketing Cloud via a boolean field for the selected regions and in Salesforce Cloud via 3 text area fields.

What's the best way to write the if/else clauses to consider this scenario (get the 3 values of 6) without getting tangled in the ifs? I was thinking if there is a way of ''grouping'' these values in batches of 2?

I have decided to apply a corresponding ''text label'' to the selected boolean value of True which I will then use when I update the Salesforce object where we store these preferences:

```
 IF (@PlacesEurope == 'True') THEN 
    SET @RegionUnu='Europe & Britain'
    ELSE 
 ENDIF

  IF (@PlacesSouthAmerica == 'True') THEN 
    SET @RegionDoi='South America'
    ELSE 
 ENDIF

   IF (@PlacesNorthCentralAmerica == 'True') THEN 
    SET @RegionTrei='North & Central America'
    ELSE 
   ENDIF

   IF (@PlacesAfricaMiddleEast == 'True') THEN 
    SET @RegionPatru='Africa & The middle East'
    ELSE 
   ENDIF

    IF (@PlacesAUSNZ == 'True') THEN 
    SET @RegionCinci='Australia & New Zeeland'
    ELSE 
   ENDIF

    IF (@PlacesAsia == 'True') THEN 
    SET @RegionSase='Asia'
    ELSE 
   ENDIF
```

I have attached a snippet of the UX.

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Giulietta
[image]

Comment: I think this post is rather hard to read. But i am not a native speaker. Could you maybe rephrase your aim that it becomes clearer?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use nested `if` statements or use `elseif` in your if statements. For example,

```
IF (@PlacesEurope == 'True') THEN 
    SET @RegionUnu='Europe & Britain'


ELSEIF (@PlacesSouthAmerica == 'True') THEN 
    SET @RegionDoi='South America'
    ELSE 
 ENDIF

   IF (@PlacesNorthCentralAmerica == 'True') THEN 
    SET @RegionTrei='North & Central America'


   ELSEIF (@PlacesAfricaMiddleEast == 'True') THEN 
    SET @RegionPatru='Africa & The middle East'
    ELSE 
   ENDIF

    IF (@PlacesAUSNZ == 'True') THEN 
    SET @RegionCinci='Australia & New Zeeland'


    ELSEIF (@PlacesAsia == 'True') THEN 
    SET @RegionSase='Asia'
    ELSE 
   ENDIF
```